# How to equalize the size of the list collection Java

Tags: java, android, for-loop, arraylist, iterator

I have a collection of lists that contain data from a streamed sensor. I wrote a for loop to form it to the format that I would later use to send it to another place (web server). However, sometimes the size of the lists differs by 1 or 2, and when it does the code will throw an out of bounds exception.

This is the code I use to assemble the format,

```java
for (int i = 0; i < acceleroElaps.size(); i++) {
    HashMap data = new HashMap();
    data.put("person", "Adi");
    data.put("tool", "Accelerometer");
    data.put("time", acceleroTime.get(i));
    data.put("elapsed", acceleroElaps.get(i));
    data.put("xaxis", acceleroXval.get(i));
    data.put("yaxis", acceleroYval.get(i));
    data.put("zaxis", acceleroZval.get(i));

    accelData.add(data);
}
```

Sometimes one of the lists doesn't have the same size. I've tried to iterate it over with iterator like this

```java
ListIterator<String> iterAT = acceleroTime.listIterator();
ListIterator<String> iterAE = acceleroElaps.listIterator();
ListIterator<String> iterAX = acceleroXval.listIterator();
ListIterator<String> iterAY = acceleroYval.listIterator();
ListIterator<String> iterAZ = acceleroZval.listIterator();

while (iterAT.hasNext() && iterAE.hasNext() && iterAX.hasNext() && iterAY.hasNext() && iterAZ.hasNext()){
    String at = iterAT.next();
    String ae = iterAE.next();
    String ax = iterAX.next();
    String ay = iterAY.next();
    String az = iterAZ.next();
    HashMap data = new HashMap();
    data.put("person", "Adi");
    data.put("tool", "Accelerometer");
    data.put("time", at);
    data.put("elapsed", ae);
    data.put("xaxis", ax);
    data.put("yaxis", ay);
    data.put("zaxis", az);
    accelData.add(data);
    a++;
    f++;
}
```

However, this would throw `ConcurrentModificationException`, so I tried to equalize the size of the lists, because it just differs 1 or 2 data points. Or maybe there's another solution? I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: While I cannot make sense of this Question, I get the feeling that your overwrought use of lists and maps should be replaced with a custom class, likely a `record`, to hold that data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution, and what I did is create a function to find the smallest list.

```
private int theSmallestVal(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e){
    int[] val = {a, b, c, d, e};
    Arrays.sort(val);
    return val[0];
}
```

Then I call the function like this:

```
al = theSmallestVal(acceleroTime.size(),acceleroElaps.size(), acceleroXval.size(),
                    acceleroYval.size(), acceleroZval.size());
```

After I found the smallest the value, I use that value to be the reference value to be iterated by for `i`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < al; i++) {
     HashMap data = new HashMap();
     data.put("person", "Adi");
     data.put("tool", "Accelerometer");
     ....
     ....
     ....
 }
```

By doing so, I could avoid out of bound exception.